# How do I upload a zipped file to Posit Cloud without it automatically unzipping?

Tags: r, zip, gtfs, gtfstools, rstudio-cloud

I am trying to read a GTFS file in RStudioCloud. The function `read_gtfs()` from package `{gtfstools}` requires a zipped file as input. However, when I upload the zipped GTFS file to RStudioCloud, it automatically unzips and opens the file.

I can't find any button in RStudioCloud to disable automatic unzipping, or to zip the file again. How can I solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is probably a better fit for https://community.rstudio.com/ since it's specific to their products and not really programming in general.